# bindService() returns false but unbindService() needs to be called?

Tags: android, service, ipc

My app uses a service provided by another (of my) apps. I am using a [bound service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) wit a `Messenger` to access and communicate with it (and as it is a different app, it is also a remote service).

When I call `bindService` with a proper intent, and the call returns `false` (as expected when the APK providing the service is not around), I assumed from the documentation and the example code, that I do not need to `unbind` the `ServiceConnection`. However, when doing so on my Galaxy Nexus (Jelly Bean) device, I get the well-known `ServiceConnectionLeaked` message when finishing the `Activity`.

I have salvaged that this by doing

```
if (!ctxt.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
    try { 
        ctxt.unbindService(serviceConnection);
    } catch (Throwable t) {}
    // Clean up 
    return;
}
// Store serviceConnection for future use
```

I am curious: Did I just miss something in the documentation and is it supposed to work this way? I added the `try ... catch` to make sure that even if this behavior is indeed different on other devices or Android versions my app is not (negatively) affected by it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

General speaking, a ServiceConnection is always allocated and registered by the framework, regardless of whether `bindService()` call return true or false. See bindService() implementation in [android.app.ContextImpl](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#L1410):

```
public boolean bindService(Intent service, ServiceConnection conn, int flags, int userHandle) {
    IServiceConnection sd;
    if (conn == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("connection is null");
    }
    if (mPackageInfo != null) {
        // A new ServiceDispatcher will be created and registered along with 
        // ServiceConnection in LoadedApk.mService for your application context.
        sd = mPackageInfo.getServiceDispatcher(conn, getOuterContext(),
                mMainThread.getHandler(), flags);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not supported in system context");
    }
    try {
        ... ...
        return res != 0;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You should always unbind the service when you are done with it, as suggested by [the official dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binding), as a good programming manner:

> - To disconnect from the service, call unbindService().
>
>   When your client is destroyed, it will unbind from the service, but you should always unbind when you're done interacting with the service or when your activity pauses so that the service can shutdown while its not being used. (Appropriate times to bind and unbind is discussed more below.)

The ServiceConnectionLeaked is raised when framework start performing a final cleanup (for instance, when your app is quit) and found there are unregistered ServiceConnection, and the framework will then try to unbind it for you. See removeContextRegistrations() implementation in [android.app.LoadedApk](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/LoadedApk.java#L526):

```
public void removeContextRegistrations(Context context,
        String who, String what) {
    final boolean reportRegistrationLeaks = StrictMode.vmRegistrationLeaksEnabled();
    ... ...
    //Slog.i(TAG, "Receiver registrations: " + mReceivers);
    HashMap<ServiceConnection, LoadedApk.ServiceDispatcher> smap =
        mServices.remove(context);
    if (smap != null) {
        Iterator<LoadedApk.ServiceDispatcher> it = smap.values().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            LoadedApk.ServiceDispatcher sd = it.next();
            ServiceConnectionLeaked leak = new ServiceConnectionLeaked(
                    what + " " + who + " has leaked ServiceConnection "
                    + sd.getServiceConnection() + " that was originally bound here");
            leak.setStackTrace(sd.getLocation().getStackTrace());
            Slog.e(ActivityThread.TAG, leak.getMessage(), leak);
            if (reportRegistrationLeaks) {
                StrictMode.onServiceConnectionLeaked(leak);
            }
            try {
                ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().unbindService(
                        sd.getIServiceConnection());
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // system crashed, nothing we can do
            }
            sd.doForget();
        }
    }
    mUnboundServices.remove(context);
    //Slog.i(TAG, "Service registrations: " + mServices);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it is still not consistent with the samples (e.g. RemoteService in ApiDemos does also only unbind if `onServiceConnected()` was called). However, since with your help I can now see that even the high level description seem to allow for such an interpretation, I will accept the answer.